# Wavy curve: Imaginary denominator.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$\cfrac{(3r^2-8r+5)}{(4r^2-3r+7)}>0$$
Find range of $r$.

So, the numerator gets simplified into $$(3r-5)(r-1)$$
But the denominator is imaginary, if it wasn't imaginary then I would have easily found the range. I don't know how to approach imaginary denominators. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quadratic function is convex and if the roots are imaginary, then it doesn't cross the $x$-axis, that is the denominator is always positive.

Hence you just have to find the condition such that the numerator is positive.

Answer (score 0):

We have $4r^2-3r+7 >0$ for all real $r$, thus

$$\frac{(3r^2-8r+5)}{(4r^2-3r+7)}>0 \iff (3r-5)(r-1) >0.$$

Can you proceed ?